# Functional Programming: Sum of properties

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I am trying to implement a function in JS [using Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/0.20.1/docs/#) that takes a list of objects and returns the sum of specific properties. E.g.

```
var l = [
  {a: 1, b: 2, c:  0},
  {a: 1, b: 3, c: -1},
  {a: 1, b: 4, c:  0},
]
func(['a', 'b'], l)
-> {a: 3, b: 9}
```

In principle, I would need a function like this:

```
R.map(R.props($1, _), $2)
```

What is the most elegant way to implement something like this in functional programming? `R.map(R.props)` does not work for obvious reasons. I tried to use some combinations with `R.compose` or `R.pipe` but I had no luck

Comment: Shouldn't the `b` prop be equal to 9?

Comment: You are totally right! Sorry, I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would break this into two parts:

```
const fnOverProp = R.curry((fn, prop, list) => fn(R.pluck(prop, list)));

const fnOverProps = R.curry((fn, props, list) => 
    R.fromPairs(R.zip(props)(R.map(fnOverProp(fn, __, list), props))));
```

(I'm sorry, I've got a creative block on naming here.  These names are pretty awful.)

You could use it like this:

```
fnOverProp(R.sum, 'b', list); //=> 9
fnOverProps(R.sum, ['a', 'b'], list); //=> {a: 3, b: 9}
const sumOverProps = fnOverProps(R.sum);
sumOverProps(['a', 'c'], list); //=> {a: 3, c: -1}
```

Note first that I generalize your idea to make `sum` a parameter.  It just made sense to me that this was not the only thing one might want to do with such a function.

Then I break it into a function that operates on a single property name.  This strikes me as quite useful on its own.  You might not need to do this for a whole list of them, and this function is worth using on its own.

Then I wrap this in a function that maps the first function over a list of properties.  Note that this is really a fairly simple function:

```
(fn, props, list) => R.map(fnOverProp(fn, R.__, list), props)
```

wrapped inside two wrappers to convert the flat list of results into the object output you're looking for.  `R.zip(props)(<thatFn>, props)` turns `[3, -1]` into `[['a', 3], ['c', -1]]` and then `R.fromPairs` turns that into `{a: 3, c: -1}`.

This does not give you your single-line implementation you say you want.  Obviously you could fold the definition of the first function into the second, but I don't think that gains you much.  And even if it could be made points-free, I would expect that would simply reduce readability in this case.

You can see this in action in the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?code=const%20list%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7Ba%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%202%2C%20c%3A%20%200%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Ba%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%203%2C%20c%3A%20-1%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Ba%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%204%2C%20c%3A%20%200%7D%2C%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20fnOverProp%20%3D%20R.curry%28%28fn%2C%20prop%2C%20list%29%20%3D%3E%20fn%28R.pluck%28prop%2C%20list%29%29%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20fnOverProps%20%3D%20R.curry%28%28fn%2C%20props%2C%20list%29%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20%20R.fromPairs%28R.zip%28props%29%28R.map%28fnOverProp%28fn%2C%20__%2C%20list%29%2C%20props%29%29%29%29%3B%0A%0AfnOverProp%28R.sum%2C%20%27b%27%2C%20list%29%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%209%0AfnOverProps%28R.sum%2C%20%5B%27a%27%2C%20%27b%27%5D%2C%20list%29%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%7Ba%3A%203%2C%20b%3A%209%7D%0Aconst%20sumOverProps%20%3D%20fnOverProps%28R.sum%29%3B%0AsumOverProps%28%5B%27a%27%2C%20%27c%27%5D%2C%20list%29%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%7Ba%3A%203%2C%20c%3A%20-1%7D%0A)**.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be defined as a reducer over the list of objects. Given some initial state of the result, we want a function that can sum the results of the two object's properties, where `props` is the list of properties we are interested in:

```
reduce(useWith(mergeWith(add, [identity, pick(props)]))
```

You then have two options as to whether the list is potentially non-empty or is guaranteed to have at lest one object. If the list is guaranteed to be non-empty, the initial value of the reducer can simply be the head of the list, serving the tail as the list to iterate over.

```
const func = (props, objs) =>
  reduce(useWith(mergeWith(add), [identity, pick(props)]), pick(props, head(objs)), tail(objs))
```

If however the list could potentially be empty, the `reduce` function must be initialised with the empty values (zero in this case).

```
const func = (props, objs) =>
  reduce(useWith(mergeWith(add), [identity, pick(props)]), pick(props, map(flip(objOf)(0), props)), objs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
function add(a, b){  
   return Object.keys(a).reduce(function(p, c){
     p[c] += a[c];
     return p;
   }, b);
}

console.log(R.reduce(add, {a:0, b:0, c:0}, l))
```

This is another approach :

```
R.pipe(R.map(R.props(['a', 'b', 'c'])), R.transpose, R.map(R.sum))(l);
```

Comment: This is a correct solution for sure, but it is not very elegant. Ideally, I am looking for a single line expressing what I want to compute. And also I'd like to apply the solution to other problems that might arise in similar contexts.

Comment: The second approach expressed in single line, hope this may help.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking more for something like `R.pipe(R.map(R.props), R.transpose, R.map(R.sum))(['a', 'b', 'c'], l)`. The trick to make something like this work is actually the concept in functional programming that I did not understand, yet.

Comment: Ah, `R.useWith` looks pretty usefull. I'm almost there: `R.pipe(R.useWith(R.map, [R.props, R.identity]), R.transpose, R.map(R.sum)) (['a', 'b'], [{a:1,b:2}, {a:2,b:2}])`